# Minecraft launcher won't open

Tags: unity, java, launcher, minecraft

I have a problem with my Minecraft launcher. I go and start up the launcher, then everything seems to be working right at first, but then it stays on the loading screen. This is what is says:
[image: Screenshot]

Please help me, and please be thorough because I'm not good with Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Just close it and open it until it works. It's a Minecraft bug.

Comment: Try the following:

    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default